# Async method not returning control back to caller method

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have the following code

```
class Program
{
    public  async  Task<bool> StartMyTask()
    {
        await Foo();

        return true;

    }

    public async Task<bool> Foo()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loop");
        }
        return true;

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();

        var myTask = obj.StartMyTask();     
        Console.WriteLine("Before Task Return");                                    


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

According to my understanding when "await Foo()" gets called, a thread will be created which will execute the "Foo()" method and the control would be returned back to the caller (Main method).

By considering this, "Before Task Return" should be printed before the "Foo()" method completes. But its not happening, first the "Foo()" method completes and then "Before Task Return" is displayed.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, no thread is created for `Foo`, and since it doesn't actually do any asynchronous work, it will block until the loop is done.

Comment: In short async methods those doesn't do any truly async work works the same as not async.

Comment: I am using await with "Foo()" in "StartMyTask" method. Shouldn't it wait for Foo to complete and return the control back to Main method ? @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: Yes it should, doesn't it do that? Your question seems to indicate it does, it completes the entire call to `StartMyTask`, including the entire loop, before `"Before Task return"` gets printed.

Comment: No. If its doing that then "Before Task Return" should be printed before the Foo execution , but its not doing that @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: Correct, it is, as you said, waiting for `Foo` to complete before it returns control back to the Main method. Please go through what you're saying and be specific.

Comment: yes, shouldn't "Before Task return" be printed before the complete Foo execution ? @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: No, not the way you've written your code. As I said, your understanding of async/await is wrong. Neither of those two keywords create new threads. Since you're not *actually* doing asynchronous work here, your code is behaving exactly as it would if you removed async/await keywords and did everything synchronously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194941/discussion-between-lasse-vagsaether-karlsen-and-waleed-naveed).

Comment: Since your Async is not awaiting anything, it will run synchronously. You should get a warning in the compiler to this effect.

Comment: StartMyTask is awaiting at Foo @theMayer

Comment: If your write following in your StartMytask method :  `await Task.Delay(100);
        await Foo();`  you will get  output you want :)

Comment: short version: async != threads (they are related topics, but **not the same**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> According to my understanding when "await Foo()" gets called, a thread will be created which will execute the "Foo()" method and the control would be returned back to the caller (Main method).

No, absolutely not. `async` and `await` do not create threads on their own. [`async` allows you to use `await`, and `await` will "asynchronously wait" - i.e., pause the method, return, and then resume the method when its operation completes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Note that the compiler is giving you a warning that you have a method marked `async` but **it will run synchronously**. So the compiler is already telling you exactly what's wrong.

If you *want* to use a background thread, you can use `Task.Run` to call the synchronous `Foo` method:

```
public async Task<bool> StartMyTask()
{
  await Task.Run(() => Foo());
  return true;
}

public bool Foo()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Loop");
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I was feverishly trying to answer this before the Stephen Clearys and Eric Lipperts of the world could.  Oh well.

Comment: I was awaiting his answer.

Comment: When you say `control goes back to caller`, please can you tell me whether the caller uses the same thread for subsequent code execution as that used to invoke the await function?

Comment: @variable: Yes. From the runtime's perspective, the thread called a method that returned a task. The thread then continues executing after the method returns.

Comment: Then why is it said that thread is returned to thread pool at the await.

Comment: @variable: That's a simplification. A thread pool thread is returned to the thread pool only at a top-level `await`.

Answer (score -1):

Since your Foo method creates no task then your code wont diverge as you expect, but making it as follows resolves your concerns:

```
public async Task<bool> Foo()
    {
       return await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Loop");
           }
           return true;
       });
    }
```